# Ising model 2D and mean field theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, ising-model, mean-field-theory

Consider the 2D Ising model. Now, let's divide it into 4-spins blocks and treat the interaction inside each block exactly, while applying the mean-field approximation to the interaction between blocks.

I'm supposed to show that the magnetization is given by

$$ m = \frac{e^{4K}\sinh(8Km)+2\sinh(4km)}{e^{4k}\cosh(8km)+4\cosh(4km)+2+2e^{-4k}}$$

where $K = \frac{J}{k_BT}$.

**Attempt**

My professor started by writing the Hamiltonian for the system,

$$H(\{s_i\},J) = -J \sum_{\langle ij\rangle}^{(1)}s_is_j$$

and immediately proceeded to write the configurations, then terms like

$$- e^{4K}(e^{8Km}\pm e^{-8Km})$$

for 4 $+$ spins, and so on. However, it was a huge leap and I cannot fill in the gaps. I was looking for some pointers, if possible.

Comment: Did you ask your professor for hints? He might have been *wanting* you to ask him.

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin I did. He just sped through the exercise. I think he thought it is not an important exercise, but still I'd like to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each spin in a 4-spin block interacts with two outer spins. This is the reason why it is hard to write exact probabilities of 4-spins configurations. In the mean-field theory, random outer spins are replaced by their mean value, $m$, and the energy of a block acquires the following form
$$
E(\{s\}) = -J(s_1s_2+s_2s3+s_3s_4+s_4s_1) - 2 J m (s_1+s_2+s_3+s_4).
$$
Self-consistency condition is
$$
4m = \langle s_1+s_2+s_3+s_4 \rangle = \frac{\sum\limits_{\{s\}} 
(s_1+s_2+s_3+s_4) e^{-E(\{s\})/k_BT}}{\sum\limits_{\{s'\}} e^{-E(\{s'\})/k_BT}}
$$
I think this formula is equivalent to the one you want to obtain.

Comment: Wow, I never thought of it like that. Thank you very much!